# How to interpret negative association in multivariate analysis?

Tags: logistic

[image]

In no user of antidepressant group, the crude coefficient is 2.20 and the adjusted coefficient is 2.58. How can I interpret this in my thesis because anxiety risk is decreased in the adjusted model?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what the specifications look like here. For example, it's not clear how you can have both variables in the model since they are linearly dependent unless one of them is a relabeled intercept. But then, it's not all that surprising that the intercept changes when you add covariates.